# NServiceBus Message Handlers and Retries

Tags: nservicebus

I have the following problem with `NServiceBus`.
After an exception in an h `NServicebus` I Log to Application Insights.
If the error is not transient the log is repeated every retry till the message goes in the error queue.

There is a way in the handler to recognize if I am in the first iteration or in one of the retries without implementing custom code?

I have seen that there is a global Notification System, But I will need to have it at `Handler level`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the message headers.

- Immediate retries: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/headers#retries-handling-headers-nservicebus-flretries
- Delayed retries: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/headers#retries-handling-headers-nservicebus-retries

`public Task Handle(MyMessage message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
{
    var numberImmediateRetries = context.MessageHeaders[NServiceBus.Headers.ImmediateRetries];
    var numberDelayedRetries = context.MessageHeaders[NServiceBus.Headers.DelayedRetries];
}`

Comment: Hi, I have tried this solution, but in my project the Immediate Retries header is always null, only the Delayed Retries header is not Empty when the message is put on delayed retries. I am using NServicebus 6. Maybe I am missing something when configuring the Endpoint?

Comment: the immediate retries can't be tracked via headers as transports usually will rollback the failed message and re-read it from the transport. This approach doesn't allow to modify the headers of the message. As of now, it's not really possible to know how many immediate retries happened outside of the recoverability policy which will receive this information from the transport.